# Compilation issue regarding ragged2e.sty

Tags: errors

I'm trying to compile a tex file for my thesis and I keep getting a persistent error:

```
[LaTeX] finished with exit code 1
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ms/ragged2e.sty:144:Undefined control sequence \if@raggedtwoe@footmisc
```

The exact text from the log file is:

```
 (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ms/ragged2e.sty
Package: ragged2e 2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty
Package: everysel 2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)

ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 126.
)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@EverySelectfont@Init 

l.144 \if@raggedtwoe@footmisc

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

This seems to be the only error I get when I try to compile my document. Upon crashing out of the building sequence I get diverted to the offending line in the offending file (as per usual with tex) and I can see that the file `ragged2e.sty` does indeed contain a logical control command:

```
\if@raggedtwoe@footmisc
  \RequirePackage{footmisc}[2002/08/28]
\fi
```

I have made sure that the footmisc package is installed on my machine (it is) and that my main file contains the command `\usepackage{footmisc}` (it does). My understanding is that `\RequirePackage` is essentially the same as `\usepackage` when used after `\documentclass` (which is the case here).

I suspect that I am simply not using the correct version of footmisc, since I recently did a complete update of all texlive components using `YaST`. According to `YaST` the version of this package I have installed is:

```
2012.67.5.5bsvn23330-5.5.2
```

If this is the cause, then should I log in as root and simply edit out the version of the package asked for (the `[2002/08/28]` bit)? I don't get feelings of good juju about having to edit LaTeX source code! :-S

After re-installing all my tex-live distribution I re-compiled my thesis and the same error comes out. The full output of the log file for the run this morning is listed below:

```
*****
*****     LaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/dave/Documents/latex/thesis"
*****     latex -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nyn
orsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbia
nc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorb
ian, welsh, loaded.
(./settings.tex (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (./warwickthesis.sty
*************************************************************
** Warwick Thesis Style File Sept 1996 
*************************************************************
) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/paralist/paralist.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/mdwtools/mdwlist.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/marginnote/marginnote.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/breakurl/breakurl.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/units/units.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/mhchem/mhchem.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/twoopt.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/sidecap/sidecap.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty)) (./main.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (./main.out)
(./main.out) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ms/ragged2e.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty
ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@EverySelectfont@Init 

l.144 \if@raggedtwoe@footmisc

)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
<./pics/crest_fullcolour.eps> (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
<./pics/the_warwick_uni_blue.eps> [1] [2] (./main.toc
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd)) [1] [2] (./parts/declaration.tex
[3]
Overfull \hbox (3.03625pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 54--55
[]\T1/cmr/m/it/10.95 Ignition cal-cu-la-tions us-ing a re-duced coupled-mode el
ectron-ion en-ergy ex-change model\T1/cmr/m/n/10.95 , 

Overfull \vbox (5.29999pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[4])
Overfull \vbox (1.39674pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[5] [6] (./parts/shouts.tex
Underfull \vbox (badness 3199) has occurred while \output is active [7])
Overfull \vbox (1.39674pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[8] (./parts/abstract.tex) [9] [10] (./parts/symbols.tex [11])
Overfull \vbox (1.39674pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[12] (./parts/introduction.tex
Chapter 1.
<./pics/phase_space.eps> [1]
Overfull \vbox (1.39674pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[2]) (./parts/appendix.tex) (./main.bbl [3]

Package natbib Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 6.

)

Package caption Warning: Unused \captionsetup[subfigure] on input line 52.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

[4] (./main.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on main.dvi (18 pages, 43140 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.
```

Comment: WIthout some minimal example that we can copy and poste to our own system, it will be very hard to help.

Comment: Please post the correct error message, how it appears on the console or `.log` file of a LaTeX run. The undefined command is shown at the end of the first line of the quoted code in the error message. An shortened error message of some IDE might get it wrong.

Comment: `\RequirePackage{footmisc}[2002/08/28]` is on line 145, but the error is thrown on line 144, one line before! Also *DO NOT* change required dates. The purpose of this date is, that the package must have this or a newer version. Using an older version might mean, that a needed feature or bug fix is not available and will break code in obscure ways. Removing the date will not update the package. BTW, the current version of `footmisc` is 2011/06/06 v5.5b.

Comment: OK so that must mean that the error is thrown due to the logical 'if' that is used on line 144, no?

Comment: Sorry if I'm using this system incorrectly, I am new to this! I have amended my original post to include the excerpt from the log file...

Comment: @DaveChapman: The excerpt from the `.log` file shows, that the undefined command is `\@EverySelectfont@Init`, not `\if@raggedtwoe@footmisc`. The command name indicates, the problem is related to `\RequirePackage{everysel}`. The latest version of that package is 2011/10/28 v1.2. Therefore I suggest, that you try this version first to check, whether problem is already fixed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks for the advice. I have looked into the everysel package and I can confirm that I have it installed. It comes as part of texlive-ms, no? As I said before, I downloaded ALL the texlive library, so how could I not have an up-to-date build of any of these standard packages? What do you suggest I look at in light of this? Cheers.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek:My friend has just tried compiling the directory and he has no problems. I therefore assumed I must have a corrupted file or similar so I re-installed the entire texlive directory from YaST (I'm using OpenSUSE 12.3 by the way)... and I STILL cannot compile my document! What on Earth is going on!? :-S

Comment: @DaveChapman: Compare the `.log` files. Have you tried an up-to-date `everysel`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek:I have attached the full log file output to the end of the initial question with an EDIT marker, as before. Hopefully this will help you diagnose the problem. P.S. My laptop (running fedora 19) has no problem compiling this document. It only seems to be an issue on this machine.

Comment: @DaveChapman: I tried the packages, given in the console log, but I cannot reproduce the problem. The console log shows that `ragged2e` was loaded by `sidecap` in `\AtBeginDocument`. You could try loading `ragged2e` explicitly at the beginning. A real [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful to analyze the problem. Adding `\listfiles` to the `.tex` file lets LaTeX print a list of the package and class versions in the console/`.log` file.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Just wanted to let you know that the issue is sorted. I specifically laoded ragged2e before the sidecap package and this appears to have fixed everything! Thank you so much for your help with this issue :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 2):

An answer from my comments:

- Package `footmisc`:

  `\RequirePackage{footmisc}[2002/08/28]` is on line 145, but the error is thrown on line 144, one line before! Also DO NOT change required dates. The purpose of this date is, that the package must have this or a newer version. Using an older version might mean, that a needed feature or bug fix is not available and will break code in obscure ways. Removing the date will not update the package. BTW, the current version of footmisc is 2011/06/06 v5.5b.
- Package `everysel`:

  The excerpt from the `.log` file shows, that the undefined command is `\@EverySelectfont@Init`, not `\if@raggedtwoe@footmisc`. The command name indicates, the problem is related to `\RequirePackage{everysel}`. The latest version of that package is 2011/10/28 v1.2. Therefore I suggest, that you try this version first to check, whether problem is already fixed.
- Still it is difficult to reproduce the problem. I tried the packages, given in the console log, but I cannot reproduce the problem. The console log shows that `ragged2e` was loaded by `sidecap` in `\AtBeginDocument`. You could try loading `ragged2e` explicitly at the beginning.

Loading  `ragged2e` before `sidecap` seems to have indeed solved the issue according to Dave Chapman's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179085/compilation-issue-regarding-ragged2e-sty?noredirect=1#comment415042_179085).

Comment: Just to add my experience: I had a similar problem and I fixed it installing the latest version of `everysel`.